# Pass value from Content page to Master Page - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am new to programming. I am working on a web application, where i have used two master pages, one master page for login and the another for rest of the application. In login page the login details are captured and stored in Session if credentials are right,

```
Session["identity"] = txtLogin.Text;
```

Then the user is directed to the home page.

I want to set the session value captured previously to the labelbox in another masterpage, which will eventually display the login id of user in all the pages. When i try to assign it to the labelbox in master.cs page,i am getting the error, "the name doesn't exist in current context". How to fix the issue.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblusername" class="Label" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

lblusername.text = Session["identity"].ToString();
```

Comment: Or you could just put the code in the master page's code-behind, with a check for `Session["identity"] != null`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton the issue i am facing is, even though i have labelbox with id-"lblusername" when i assign value to it in code behind, it shows, the name"lblusername" does not exists in current context.

Comment: It looks like setting the text in the another master page's code-behind is the way to go. That way the code is only in one place. If you put the code in every page, it will be annoying to have to edit it for every page if some change is needed, and it would be easy to forget to add the code when you create a new page.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, i tried but the same error pops out. Is it not possible to set value to labelbox/textbox in masterpages?

Comment: It is definitely possible. Try adding another asp:Label with a different ID to the master page and see if you can refer to that in the master page's code-behind, in case the lblusername label is broken somehow.

Comment: @AndrewMorton i tried same issue. Is there any naming convention to be followed when trying to assign value to labelbox in masterpage

Comment: Can you access any of the master page's controls from its code-behind? Does the master page have the attribute `CodeBehind="Site.master.vb"` (with the appropriate .vb filename) in the `<%@ Master` part? Does the code-behind file start with `Public Class SiteMaster
 Inherits MasterPage` (with the appropriate class name)?

Answer (score 0):

when you use master page and content pages one of the most important parts is checking event sequences.

```
    //Content page PreInit event.
    //Master page controls Init event.
    //Content controls Init event.
    //Master page Init event.
    //Content page Init event.
    //Content page Load event.
    //Master page Load event.
    //Master page controls Load event.
    //Content page controls Load event.
    //Content page PreRender event.
    //Master page PreRender event.
    //Master page controls PreRender event.
    //Content page controls PreRender event.
    //Master page controls Unload event.
    //Content page controls Unload event.
    //Master page Unload event.
    //Content page Unload event.
```

check  event sequences and check which event you assign value to session and in which event you get it from session.